# phase loss detection

Tags: power-electronics

Hi I use this circuit to detect phase loose, so if one of the phase lost , the phase loss signal will be high, the problem in this circuit are.
1-if the input voltage less at 50% it give phase loss , i did try to increase the resistors (R99,R100 and R102) this make work but it cause another problem
is when i have phase loss and if input voltage more than 380Vac , the circuit does not detect phase loss becuase all optocoupler are on.
So how can i make this circuit work right like if i loss one phase , the phase loss signal be high and is not turn off at high input voltage and also how can avoid getting phase loss when the voltage at less than 50%[image]

Comment: Why not ask on the electrical engineering stack?

Comment: You need to write a specification. This should include the required operating voltage range, frequency range and maximum response time. It looks like English is not your first language. You should mention this in your user profile and we will help you tidy up your post.